# How to catch error in callback function JS?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, error-handling, async-await, callback

I want to catch error in a callback function.

```js
(async function(){
    function wait(ms){
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            setTimeout(resolve, ms);
        });
    }

    async function test(){
        while(true) {
            if (window.err){
                throw 'This is an error!';
            }
            await wait(500);
        }
    }

    
    try {
        console.log('running ...');

        window.err = false;
        setTimeout(function(){
            window.err = true;
        }, 1000);

        test();
    
        await wait(3000);
        console.log('end')
        console.log('done')
    }
    catch(err){
        // How do i catch error of "test" function in this
        console.log('end')
        console.log('error')
    }
})()
```

....................................................................................................................................................................................................
How do i catch error of **test** function in this?
My englist is not good, help me pls! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`test` is an asynchronous function, if you call it without awaiting it the errors will be ignored.

Instead of `test()` use `await test()`.

Or if you don't want to await it and just be notified when an error happens, you can use `Promise.catch`:

```js
test().catch(err => {
  // Handle the error in some way
  console.error(err)
})
```

Comment: I know it, but i want to run a function like (multi thread). It check a condition in everytime!

Comment: @nguyenphuong that's not possible. JS is single threaded. Unless you use web workers.

Comment: @nguyenphuong Can you give more details. What are you trying to achieve? I may be able to show you with generators.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to catch the error from the test function you can try like this

```
(async function(){
    function wait(ms){
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            setTimeout(resolve, ms);
        });
    }

    async function test(){
      return new Promise((resolve, reject)  => {
       try {
          while(true) {
            if (window.err){
                throw 'This is an error!';
            }
            await wait(500);
            resolve();
          }
       } catch(err) {
             reject(err) // here we are catching the error and throw it back to the caller 
       }
      });
    }

    
    try {
        console.log('running ...');

        window.err = false;
        setTimeout(function(){
            window.err = true;
        }, 1000);

       try {
         await test();
       } catch (err) {
         console.log(err) // here we get the error from the test
       }

    
        await wait(3000);
        console.log('end')
        console.log('done')
    }
    catch(err){
        // How do i catch error of "test" function in this
        console.log('end')
        console.log('error')
    }
})()
```

I hope it helps you out